# How to use <td> value for jquery calculation in place of <input type="number">

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have a mortgage payment calculator function on my page. This works fine. What I need to achieve is tying this calculator function to the sample table data that I also have on the page.

Basically what I am trying to achieve is to have each `<tr>` use the 'initial rate' value in that row for the `function repayment()` calculation. I then want the output of this to appear in the same `<tr>` in the 'monthly repayment' cell.

Any help checking out how I can do this using the current  would be really appreciated. My guess is that I somehow need to parse the value of every  in the interest rate column, but I don't know how to do this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#type :checkbox").click(function() {
    $("td").parent().hide();
    $("#type :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
      $("." + $(this).val()).parent().show();
    });
  });
  $("#fee :checkbox").click(function() {
    $("td").parent().hide();
    $("#fee :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
      $("." + $(this).val()).parent().show();
    });
  });
});

window.onload = function() {
  document.repaymentcalc.homevalue.onchange = repayment;
  document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.onchange = repayment;
  document.repaymentcalc.interestrate.onchange = repayment;
  document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.onchange = repayment;

}

function repayment()

{

  var x = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.value, 10);
  var y = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.interestrate.value * 100, 10) / 120000;
  var z = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.value, 10) * 12;
  var h = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.homevalue.value, 10);

  var repayment = y * x * Math.pow((1 + y), z) / (Math.pow((1 + y), z) - 1);

  var loantovalue = x / h * 100;

  var year = z / 12;

  document.getElementById("repayments").innerHTML = 'Monthly Repayment: £' + repayment.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("ltv").innerHTML = 'Loan to Value: ' + loantovalue.toFixed(1) + '%';
  document.getElementById("years").innerHTML = year + ' years';

}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="table.css">
</head>

<body style="font-family: arial;">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <section id="type">
    <p id="Mortgage Type">Mortgage Type</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t1" id="t1" />Fixed
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t2" id="t2" />Variable
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t3" id="t3" />Tracker
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t4" id="t4" checked/>All
    <br>
  </section>



  <section id="fee">
    <p id="Fee">Fee</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="f1" id="f1" />Fee
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="f2" id="f2" />No Fee
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="f3" id="f3" checked/>All
    <br>
  </section>

  <form name="repaymentcalc" action="">
    </br>

    <p>
      Home Value £
      <input type="number" id="homevalue" value="250000" style="width: 75px">
    </p>

    <p>
      Loan Amount £
      <input type="number" id="loanamount" value="200000" style="width: 75px">
    </p>

    <p>
      Interest Rate
      <input type="number" id="interestrate" value="3.00" style="width: 50px">%
    </p>

    Term
    <input type="range" id="numberpayments" value="25" min="1" max="40" style="width: 100px">
    <div id="years" style="display:inline-block;">25 years

    </div>

    <div id="repayments">Monthly Repayment: £948.42</div>

    <p>
      <div id="ltv">Loan to Value: 80.0%</div>

      </div>
  </form>

  <br>

  <div id="mortgagediv">
    <table id="mortgagetable">
      <tr class="productheader">
        <th class="lender">Lender</th>
        <th class="type">Type</th>
        <th class="inititalmths">Initital Term (mths)</th>
        <th class="inititalrate">Initial Rate (%)</th>
        <th class="svr">SVR (%)</th>
        <th class="apr">Overall APR (%)</th>
        <th class="fee">Fee (£)</th>
        <th class="ltv">LTV (%)</th>
        <th class="minamount">Min Amount (£)</th>
        <th class="maxamount">Max Amount (£)</th>
        <th class="repayment">Monthly Repayment (£)</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t1 t4">Fixed</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.64</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f3"></td>
        <td class="tg-031e">70</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">20,000</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t2 t4">Variable</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.69</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f3"></td>
        <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">20,000</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t3 t4">Tracker</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.79</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f3"></td>
        <td class="tg-031e">80</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">20,000</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t1 t4">Fixed</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.64</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f2 f3"></td>
        <td class="tg-031e">70</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">20,000</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t2 t4">Variable</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.69</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f2 f3"></td>
        <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">20,000</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t3 t4">Tracker</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.79</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f2 f3"></td>
        <td class="tg-031e">80</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">20,000</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: use `data-default-date='12'` in `tr` like `<tr data-default-date='12'><td></td></tr>` to store some default  value

Answer (score 1):

You can get value of cells in each row and then place resulting value in the last cell.

```
$('#mortgagetable tr').each(function() {
    var value = '';

    $(this).find(".tg-031e").each(function() {
        value += $(this).html();    
    });

    $(this).find("td:last").html(value);
});
```

You have only to skip the first row of the table by using negative css selector

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, you're trying to compute the monthly payment given the "initial rate" for each row in the table, right?

If so, I think the following code should work.  I added a `tbody` and `thead` element to the table so it'd be easy to pull out only the "data" rows.  I added a new function called `computeRepayment` which only does the math for the repayment number.  The function `repayment` then uses that function and updates the dom accordingly (for all the onchange things).

Lastly, I made the `computeRepayment` function take an optional `rate` so that if the rate is there, it uses it.  If not, it pulls it from your input.

If this seems right, you might make the column finding a bit easier by adding a class to each of the `interestrate` elements and the `payment` elements.  Like

```
<tr class="product">
  <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
  ...
  <td class="rate tg-031e">1.79</td>
  ...
  <td class="tg-031e">20,000</td>
  <td class="payment tg-031e"></td>
</tr>
```

which would make the javascript a bit clearer to find those columns in the row.  Based on my code, it would change this

```
var initialRateCell = $row.find('td')[3];
```

to this

```
var initialRateCell = $row.find('.rate');
```

Hopefully this helps out.  I tried to comment my mods to your code snippets so it should be clear what I've proposed as a solution.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#type :checkbox").click(function() {
    $("td").parent().hide();
    $("#type :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
      $("." + $(this).val()).parent().show();
    });
  });
  $("#fee :checkbox").click(function() {
    $("td").parent().hide();
    $("#fee :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
      $("." + $(this).val()).parent().show();
    });
  });
});

window.onload = function() {
  
  document.repaymentcalc.homevalue.onchange = repayment;
  document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.onchange = repayment;
  document.repaymentcalc.interestrate.onchange = repayment;
  document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.onchange = repayment;

  // initialize on page load
  repayment();
}

function populateRepaymentTable() {          // populate repayment in table
  console.log("GO")
  $('tbody tr').each(function(idx, row) {
     var $row = $(row);
     var initialRateCell = $row.find('td')[3];
     var repaymentCell = $row.find('td').last()
     var rate = parseFloat($(initialRateCell).html());
     var repaymentVal = computeRepayment(rate);
     console.log(repaymentVal)
     $(repaymentCell).html(repaymentVal.repayment);
  }); 
}

function computeRepayment(rate) {
  var rate = rate || document.repaymentcalc.interestrate.value
  var x = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.loanamount.value, 10);
  var y = parseInt(rate * 100, 10) / 120000;
  var z = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.numberpayments.value, 10) * 12;
  var h = parseInt(document.repaymentcalc.homevalue.value, 10);

  var repayment = y * x * Math.pow((1 + y), z) / (Math.pow((1 + y), z) - 1);

  var loantovalue = x / h * 100;

  var year = z / 12;
  return {
    repayment: repayment,
    loantovalue: loantovalue,
    year: year
  }      
}
function repayment()
{
  var repaymentInfo = computeRepayment()
  document.getElementById("repayments").innerHTML = 'Monthly Repayment: £' + repaymentInfo.repayment.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("ltv").innerHTML = 'Loan to Value: ' + repaymentInfo.loantovalue.toFixed(1) + '%';
  document.getElementById("years").innerHTML = repaymentInfo.year + ' years';
  populateRepaymentTable();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="type">
  <p id="Mortgage Type">Mortgage Type</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t1" id="t1" />Fixed
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t2" id="t2" />Variable
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t3" id="t3" />Tracker
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="type" value="t4" id="t4" checked/>All
  <br>
</section>



<section id="fee">
  <p id="Fee">Fee</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="f1" id="f1" />Fee
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="f2" id="f2" />No Fee
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="fee" value="f3" id="f3" checked/>All
  <br>
</section>

<form name="repaymentcalc" action="">
  </br>

  <p>
    Home Value £
    <input type="number" id="homevalue" value="250000" style="width: 75px">
  </p>

  <p>
    Loan Amount £
    <input type="number" id="loanamount" value="200000" style="width: 75px">
  </p>

  <p>
    Interest Rate
    <input type="number" id="interestrate" value="3.00" style="width: 50px">%
  </p>

  Term
  <input type="range" id="numberpayments" value="25" min="1" max="40" style="width: 100px">
  <div id="years" style="display:inline-block;">25 years

  </div>

  <div id="repayments">Monthly Repayment: £948.42</div>

  <p>
    <div id="ltv">Loan to Value: 80.0%</div>

    </div>
</form>

<br>

<div id="mortgagediv">
  <table id="mortgagetable">
    <thead>
      <tr class="productheader">
        <th class="lender">Lender</th>
        <th class="type">Type</th>
        <th class="inititalmths">Initital Term (mths)</th>
        <th class="inititalrate">Initial Rate (%)</th>
        <th class="svr">SVR (%)</th>
        <th class="apr">Overall APR (%)</th>
        <th class="fee">Fee (£)</th>
        <th class="ltv">LTV (%)</th>
        <th class="minamount">Min Amount (£)</th>
        <th class="maxamount">Max Amount (£)</th>
        <th class="repayment">Monthly Repayment (£)</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t1 t4">Fixed</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.64</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f3"></td>
        <td class="tg-031e">70</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">20,000</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t2 t4">Variable</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.69</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f3"></td>
        <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">20,000</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t3 t4">Tracker</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.79</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f1 f3"></td>
        <td class="tg-031e">80</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">20,000</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t1 t4">Fixed</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.64</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f2 f3"></td>
        <td class="tg-031e">70</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">20,000</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t2 t4">Variable</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.69</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f2 f3"></td>
        <td class="tg-031e">75</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">20,000</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="product">
        <td class="tg-031e">Nationwide</td>
        <td class="t3 t4">Tracker</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">24</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">1.79</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.99</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">3.40</td>
        <td class="f2 f3"></td>
        <td class="tg-031e">80</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">5,000</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">20,000</td>
        <td class="tg-031e"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah that is almost it. It doesn't recalculate if I change the inputs though?

Comment: And the old `<div id="repayments">Monthly Repayment: £948.42</div>` can be removed, can I remove any other script if I take this div out, and will it make it easier to make the outputs refresh on change?

Comment: I added to the script so that it recomputes the table as you change the values in the form.  You still need the #repayments id as a place to put the output of the computation, but it can be blank to start because when the page loads, it'll run the computation and fill that div.  I think most of that javascript is necessary to accomplish what you want (though it could be refactored to be a bit cleaner).  Just for ease of reading/tweaking, I added the same code in a codepen http://codepen.io/bunnymatic/pen/GpjLBV